# Pulling Image from Public Docker Hub to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multiple Container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerrun.aws.json

I am trying to get multiple containers running on the same Elastic Beanstalk instance with a NodeJS server listening to APIs coming from a ReactJS/Webpack client - each running in respective containers. I am using a **Dockerrun.aws.json** file which is pulling the images from my public docker repository. When I deploy the just the **Dockerrun.aws.json** to Elastic Beanstalk it says that the instance is running inside the AWS console. However, I am unable to hit the URL and I get the folowing error from the logs:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/etc/init/eb-ecs.conf.disabled’: No such file or directory
  Error response from daemon: No such image: 6011d33fc722:latest
```

**My question is how to get the Elastic Beanstalk to pull and run the container on my EC2 instance?** I have already tried placing the image inside the Elastic Container Repositories with a similar result.

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "dev-server",
            "image": "sjryall/dev-server-v2:latest",
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "containerPort": 8000
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                "dev-client"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dev-client",
            "image": "sjryall/dev-client-v2:latest",
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is your image name `6011d33fc722 `. the error message says `6011d33fc722 ` is the image and `latest` is the tag.

Comment: Please post your `dockerrun.aws.json`

Comment: yes ```6011d33fc722``` is the image id. I have already posted the dockerrun.aws.json file above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a `.dockercfg` file with your authentication information to the repository and store it in an s3 bucket. This will include the credentials to authenticate yourself against the docker repository.

the file should look like this.

```
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "your_auth_string",
      "email": "your_email"
     }
   }
}
```

Then your `Dockerrun.aws.json` should have an authentication section that defines that s3 bucket and the key pointing to the file you just uploaded to s3.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "bucket-that-contains-the-file",
    "Key": "location/.dockercfg"
  }
}
```

hope this helps.

Reference:
https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/image-registries/

Comment: Thanks. But my images on docker hub are public so I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue. It states in the docs : ```Note that on Docker Hub, you can use public images without any authentication being required.```